# Why mdev or udev does not create disk nodes when used kernel is from any distribution

Tags: linux, disk, udev

I created a minimal linux init with just busybox to do experiments or use it to recover my work linux. But i got stuck and was fustruted alot that i could not find any disks in /dev. I tried both mounting udev as devtmpfs and tmpfs with mdev -s. Both none seemed to work. Lickily i tried compiling a kernel and booting it i realised kernel was the issue. I also noticed my pluged mouse light was off as if the pc was turned off

I tried kernel from both debian and ubuntu. But same result.

Now im happy with what i got. But using custom kernel means i cant make use of the already existing drivers on a target linux when i do chroot.

So i wanna know why the kernels that come with distros does not generate disk blocks

Edit 1:
My question is,why i cant find ant /dev/sdX or my external keyboard does not work when i boot with kernel from distro isos

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: i created a custom initrd rootfs with budybox. if i boot it with self compiled kernel, everything is ok. but if i use pre compiled kernel from debian or ubuntu iso,non of my disk shows up in /dev. also externel keyboard does not work. i tried both udev and mdev